# How do I keep the cron from removing a poll from my front page?

Tags: blocks, cron, polls

I am running Drupal 6 and cron from my crontab. I created a poll on a site that I have inherited and moved it into the first sidebar where it appeared until the cron ran. I can duplicate this (cron runs every hour) . How do I keep it from doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend [Elysia Cron](http://drupal.org/project/elysia_cron), it allows fine grained control of crons provided by modules (ie poll) in which you can completely disable the cron of a specific module (or change the timing from the global setting for that specific module's cron; in your case, 1 hour), which seems like something you might need to try out.  See attached for an example settings screen on a D6 site (the checked boxes mean that cron is disabled).

[image: Elysia Cron Settings]

Comment: I have installed Elysia and will play with turning thing on and off and see what might be causing this. Thanks!